# What does BluetoothGatt status 133 on Android mean?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm working on an Android app that connects to a BLE device. The device I'm using has a maximum MTU of 240, and this is the MTU size I see when I connect and request the MTU.

For several weeks now I've been developing my app using a Pixel 5a and it's been working fine. I can send and receive BLE packets up to 240 bytes, which is important to my app because I have cases where I need to send large blocks of data as efficiently as I can.

Recently I tested my app on a Samsung device, and found that I can't send packets larger than about 20 bytes. Even though the "onMtuChanged" callback reports 240, if I try to send more than 20 bytes, I rececive error number 133 in the "onCharacteristicWrite" callback, and the send fails. (I think I can still read packets up to 240 characters).

There is no definition for error code 133 in the Android documentation. I've read that serializing the output on the main thread is the solution, but I'm already doing that. I also tried pausing 200ms before each write to give the Bluetooth stack time to clear, but that doesn't work either.

I'm getting worried. The app I'm writing really needs a high MTU to function in any practical way. Does anyone know what the real meaning of error 133 is, or the real solution to the problem?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: 0x85 is just a generic error and the code itself does not really indicate the reason for the error. It would be good if you could share your code. Also, let us know if you see the write request on the remote device. Finally, you should inspect the hci log to see exactly what packets are being sent, as well as check the logcat log.

Comment: I can't share my code but I can assure you that the parts which send BLE packets are very straighforward. All of the writes occur on the same thread (which is not the main thread). I tried using WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE, but the BLE device wont' accept those writes. What is the hci log and where do I find it?

Comment: I have a way to monitor a log from the BLE device itself. It does not receive anything when I send large packets from the Samsung device.

Comment: Logcat is showing everything working up until the "onCharacteristicWrite" callback after the large packet write. This is where I see the 133 status code.

Comment: The logic of my app is to write a BLE packet, wait for "onCharacteristicWrite", and then write the next packet. A queueing system is set up to keep track of a list of packets waiting to be sent.

Comment: If I could at least find a way to detect whether the Android device I'm running on is able to send large packets or not, without actually having to try it and wait for a failure, that would be of some use.

Comment: You can use the app nRF Connect as an alternative and see if it works correctly and post the log here. Unless there are any bugs, all Android versions support writing "large" packets. You can Google "hci snoop log" to get more info about that.